# eye texturing problem

Tags: modeling

I created a simple eye and I UV unwrapped it and put eye texture on it. Then I duplicated the eye, put it in the same position and scaled it a little and I added glass texture on it. I don't know why but it doesn't look clean and looks like i added some extra cloud texture.Can you help me please. Thank you for any response.. Pictures below: [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: does it still have the cloudiness issue when the glass mesh is hidden? You need to break it down to the simplest point where the cloudiness does not appear.